# How can I change the type of a token basing on the production's type?

Tags: bison, yacc, lex

I am developing a small project using Lex and Yacc and I have to deal with mathematical expressions.

In my file syntax.y, I have these two types of production rules:

```
%union {
   char* lexeme;            
   double value;
   }

%token <lexeme>  NUM
%type <lexeme> expr
%type <value> comp_expr

expr  : expr "+" expr { $$ = strcat($1,"+"); $$ = strcat($$,$3); }
      | NUM 
      ;

comp_expr: comp_expr "+" comp_expr { $$ = $1 + $3; }
         | NUM 
         ;
```

I use "expr" in order to return the expression as a string and I use "comp_expr" in order to return the expression as a computed expression, in this case a sum.

Basing on the other parts in syntax.y (that I did not include, because here are irrelevant) I have a system that recognize properly when to use "expr" and when to use "comp_expr".

But I have an error when I use "comp_expr", because the Token NUM is declared as a lexeme, thus a string, and the production "comp_expr" has a value, thus a double, as type.

How can I assign both lexeme and value to the Token NUM? Or how can I change the value of NUM basing on production that I am using?

In addition, I post also the way I save the NUM in the file lexic.l:

```
{NUM}   { yylval.lexeme = strdup(yytext); return NUM; }
```

Thanks in advance for the attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the risk of stating the obvious, I'd suggest you convert the `NUM` to a double when you need it to be a double. Unit productions are perfect for such conversions and you happen to have one handy:

```
comp_expr: NUM { $$ = strtod($1, NULL); }
```

You could do more careful error checking with the call to `strtod` but it may be reasonable to assume that the lexeme has already been validated by the lexical scanner.

---

By the way, there's a huge problem with:

```
expr  : expr "+" expr { $$ = strcat($1,"+"); $$ = strcat($$,$3); }
```

`$1` is, presumably, the return value of a call to `strdup` in the lexical scanner. In that case, it is exactly long enough to hold the lexeme *and no longer*. So concatenating more stuff at the end is a buffer overflow; you will overwrite memory which doesn't belong to you. That will get you into trouble very quickly.

You need to allocate a new string of the correct length for the `expr`; `asprintf` is very handy for this purpose, as well as being more readable than a series of `strcat`s.

You probably should also think about the memory leak resulting from not `free`ing the `strdup`ed lexemes after you concatenate them.

Comment: Thank you, the first solution works fine and the second tip is very helpful and useful.